# Oracle: add milliseconds to my timestamp object

Tags: sql, oracle, time, oracle12c

I want to add milliseconds to my timestamp object. For example I have to increment the timestamp value by 25 milliseconds.

I took this as an example

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') as ts 
, to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.')||to_char(to_number(to_char(systimestamp,'FF')) + 250) 
,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') as ts_1 
from dual;
```

it works and increases milliseconds. But it does not affect the seconds field. For example if we add 1000 millisecods then ideally the seconds field should be incremented. We know there is way to convert a timestamp into milliseconds. Is there any way to convert the milliseconds back to timestamp ? Or if ther is any way of adding milliseconds to the timestamp object which does reflect changes in seconds filed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You add time to a timestamp by adding an interval. Intervals can go down to seconds only, but an interval of 0.001 seconds is a milliseconds interval which you can multiply with the desired value. E.g:

```
select systimestamp + interval '0.001' second * :millisecs from dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an interval literal:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '0.025' SECOND
FROM   DUAL
```

or dynamically create an interval with `NUMTODSINTERVAL`:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 25 / 1000, 'SECOND' )
FROM   DUAL
```

or, with a bind variable:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL( :milliseconds / 1000, 'SECOND' )
FROM   DUAL
```